# Javascript add style tag to head

Tags: css, dom, styles

I'm trying to add some css to an internal stylesheet with javascript. This is the code I've used:

```
function googleJS(){
    var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var newScript = doc.createElement('style');
    newScript.setAttribute('.skiptranslate { display: none; }');
    var bodyClass = doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];         
    bodyClass.insertBefore(newScript, bodyClass.childNodes[2]);
}
```

However this results in:

```
<style .skiptranslate {display: none};></style>
```

What is the proper method to use javascript to insert a style tag with the necessary CSS inside the DOM?

Thanks

Comment: as the function name suggests, `setAttribute()` sets "attributes" for elements. And that's what exactly happens with your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the name implies ([and documentation says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.setAttribute)) `Element.setAttribute`:

> Adds a new attribute or changes the value of an existing attribute on the specified element.

which is exactly what's happening on the `<style>` element. To fix this, use [`.textContent`/`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) or [a text element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createTextNode) instead of `.setAttribute()`.

```
function googleJS(){
    var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var newScript = doc.createElement('style');
    var content = doc.createTextNode('.skiptranslate { display: none; }');
    newScript.appendChild(content);
    var bodyClass = doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];         
    bodyClass.insertBefore(newScript, bodyClass.childNodes[2]);
}
```

Comment: @user208709 you're welcome, but it's really just a matter of reading the docs `:)`

Comment: Btw, is it possible to add multiple CSS attributes in the createTextNode?

Comment: Yes, it is. Why don't you just experiment with it? And, like I said, read the docs. There are rich, well-documented APIs for manipulating CSS rules. Go explore! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLStyleElement

Comment: Sorry if I sound lazy, I'm not. I'm just working on a tight schedule and the other members have left the team so I'm working on several solutions all at once and it's just this part that I couldn't find a quick solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use JQuery:
    $().css('Property-Name', 'Value');

Comment: Who said anything about jQuery? Also, this is not even equivalent to what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: `.css()` is _still_ not directly equivalent to inserting a new CSS rule.